# Angular ng-repeat no data is shown before i put td

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is fairly strange.

I have the following table directive:

```
    /**
 * Created by root on 8/4/16.
 */
angular.module('LBTable').directive('lbTable', ['tabService', function (tabService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        roles: 'all',
        templateUrl: 'js/helpers/LBTable/directives/lb-table/lb-table.html',
        scope: {
            tableData: '=',
            tableFields: '=',
            actionElement: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.filterFields = [];
            findFilterFields();
            function findFilterFields() {
                scope.tableFields.forEach(function (x) {
                    if (x.sortable == true) {
                        scope.filterFields.push(x.fieldKey);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

This has the following html:

```
<table id="table-client" class="table table-responsive" >
<thead>
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="field in tableFields" translate="{{field.headerTitle | translate}}"></th>
    <th class="text-right"
        translate="TERMS.ADMINISTRATION" ng-if="actionElement != null"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData track by item.id">
    <lb-table-element element-data="item" table-fields="tableFields"></lb-table-element>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Within this you can see another directive: `lbTableElement`

This directive looks like this:

```
    /**
 * Created by root on 8/4/16.
 */
angular.module('LBTable').directive('lbTableElement', ['tabService', function (tabService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        roles: 'all',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'js/helpers/LBTable/directives/lb-table-element/lb-table-element.html',
        scope: {
            elementData: '=',
            tableFields: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var data = scope.elementData;
        }
    }
}]);
```

And has the following html:

```
 <td ng-repeat="field in tableFields">
    {{elementData[field.fieldKey]}}
</td>
```

Nnow the `tableData` array consists of `1240` objects. But when i run this no data is displayed.

However if i reformat my html to look like this:

```
<td> <lb-table-element element-data="item" table-fields="tableFields"></lb-table-element></td>
```

The object `item` is no longer `undefined` and data is shown.

Can anyone tell me why?

[Fiddle for you to try out (simpler example)](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/3118/)

Comment: Shouldn't the template for td have something like `{{field.fieldKey}}` instead of `{{elementData[field.fieldKey]}}`? Or `<td ng-repeat="field in data">{{field.fieldKey}}</td>`

Comment: @thepio no elementData is the item and then the fieldKey is they key in the object im pulling out. Never the less the real question is why do you need the <td>

Comment: I might be just tired but you are repeating `tableFields` and inside that you are trying to show elementData which might be an array and this is why nothing prints out then you are trying to look a key in it?

Comment: @thepio check out the fiddle its way simpler

Comment: In your fiddle data rendered that you can see in console. Yep, rendered without ID, but ng-repeat works

Comment: `<lb-table-element>` is invalid child of `<tr>` and browser will reject placing it there`

Comment: Yeah your fiddle also works when you add `<td>`: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/fhq7kpzg/

Comment: @ALL problem is i need the element directive to determain what kind of <td> im creating which is impossible if the tag is not allowed :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the comments I realised what's causing your trouble. You need to fix it by setting the directive as an attribute not as an element like this:

```
<td lb-table-element element-data="item" table-fields="tableFields"></td>
```

Then you can either repeat the data in your directive or repeat it in the element itself. I'm afraid there's no other solution.